# Relation between tables without primary key

Tags: activerecord, yii, yii-relations

Two tables 1 and 2, where id_schedule in 2 table is not primary key:

[image]

Task is to get the dates from table 2. I have the following code:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'scheduleTitles' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ObjectScheduleTranslate', 'id'),
        'scheduleDates'  => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ObjectScheduleDate', array('id' => 'id_schedule'))
    );
}
```

OK, first relation works well, second (for this task, exactly) returns only one record (this one *2013-12-30 00:00:00*)which is first in screen.

Trying to use another approach, I coded the relation in first model:

```
'scheduleDates'  => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ObjectScheduleDate', 'id')
```

at second model:

```
'scheduleDatesId' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ObjectSchedule', 'id_schedule')
```

which returns my empty set.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you try to use `self::HAS_MANY`?

Comment: try something like `'scheduleDates' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ObjectScheduleDate', '', 'foreignKey' => array('id'=>'id_schedule'),`

Comment: The result is same as in the first part of my question...

Comment: Please post full SQL to re-create there tables locally.

Comment: ОК, code here https://codeo.me/3Gt